# Custom AdapterArray listview

Tags: android, listadapter, android-screen-support

Need to make a custom adapter for a few listviews

basically will work like this...

NavDrawer items:

Home

Service

Product

In Service and Product their are buttons that correspond with different sections i.e.: Specials, Accessories, All Products.

Each section has a title and a price that would populate inside a listview item. To keep it simple for now, in the future would like to add an image, but creating a custom adapter would allow for that. I am just not sure if I have the right idea, and also I am not sure how to go about creating a properly constructed CustomAdapterArray for the newest release of android from 4.0-5.1 devices.

Any Help?

Comment: what all you have tried ??

Comment: ListView with standard adapter.